# Log4j: Why do I have log entries missing when logging inside a Callable that is submitted to an ExecutorService

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, executorservice

I have something that looks along the lines of this:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(thisClass.class);
private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
...
...
public void method1() {
    Callable<Integer> callable = () -> {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        try {
            Integer i = someMethod();
            log.info("got " + i + " in " + timer.getElapsedTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("exception thrown after " + timer.getElapsedTime());
            throw e;
        }
        return i;
    };
    method2(callable);
    log.info("method1 called method2");
}

public static void method2(Callable<Integer> callable) {
    Future<Integer> future = EXECUTOR.submit(task);
    future.get();
}
```

For some reason when I use maven to run my application, where method1 is called 200 times, I can see the log entry outside of the Callable ("method1 called method2") 200 times, but I only see about ~100 entries logged for the one inside the Callable ("got i in t seconds")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using an AsyncAppender fixed the problem

Comment: Please can you add more details as to how you used AsyncAppender to fix this issue

Comment: I added a AsyncAppender in my log4j file:
`<appender name="AsyncAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
         <param name="BufferSize" value="1024"/>
         <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/></appender>`

and then 
`<root>
<level value="INFO>
<appender-ref ref="AsyncAppender">
</root>`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I actually solved it by using the logger of the calling class in the main thread. Thanks for the added detail.